# Is there an official list for iTunes / iOS version compatibility?

Tags: macos, ios, itunes

I've found [answers on this site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255909/iphone-ios-10-compatible-with-mac-os-x-10-7-5?rq=1) stating that iOS 10 is not compatible with iTunes 12.2 (the latest iTunes version available for macOS 10.7). This helped with a problem I have.

Is there an official document from Apple that shows which iOS versions are compatible with which iTunes versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iTunes#Devices

This is not an official apple document but it works.

Also, since you don't have any query about any other iOS or iTunes version, answer is link-only.